# Integral over surface vector in the language of differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to relate the idea of taking an integral over a surface vector in the language of differential geometry.

For example, the integral (in $\mathbb{R}^3$)
$$ \vec{A} = \int_{d\Omega} f d\vec{S} $$
where $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function of position.
In standard vector calculus, this is interpreted as the integral over surface vectors (resulting in a vector).
Is there a way to write this in terms of differential forms?

If we had instead
$$ A = \int_{d\Omega} \vec{f} \cdot d\vec{S} $$
where $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector function of position.
We could write this as a $2$-form $df = f_x dy \wedge dz + f_y dz \wedge dx + f_z dy \wedge dz$.
I'm trying to relate it to something like this.

Comment: I think I was asking something similar a while ago. Maybe it will help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843421/spheres-surface-area-element-using-differential-forms/3844205#3844205

Comment: $dS$ is not a form but a [density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210148/explain-densities-to-me-please).